# Is F# RC equal to RTM?

Tags: f#, version, rc, rtm

I am wondering if F# RC equal to RTM? 
If not is there any doc mentioning about that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the RC is from a couple months back.  The RTM was just released.

http://blogs.msdn.com/dsyme/archive/2010/04/12/f-2-0-released-as-part-of-visual-studio-2010.aspx

Comment: But the F# version for RC(the one released a couple months back) is 2.0 and also the F# version for RTM(the newest one) is 2.0? It is confusing to me...

Comment: Both compile the 2.0 version of the F# language.  But the assemblies themselves have version number 1.9.9.9 in the RC and 2.0.0.0 in the RTM.  (And then of course there's the 4.0.0.0 versions that ship as part of Visual Studio 2010 (10.0).)  Version numbers are always confusing.  The point is, the final version was released in April, get that.  :)

Answer (score 1):

After previous F# releases Don Syme has included detailed change notes on his blog. But I've not seen anything yet: http://blogs.msdn.com/dsyme/default.aspx

I am currently assuming no changes that are not bug fixes (RC was declared as "2.0" [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/dsyme/archive/2010/02/10/announcing-the-f-february-2010-release.aspx)).

Comment: Thank you, Everyone. Esp, thanks Richard, that was exactly what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 1):

RC stands for release candidate, therefore meaning that it s a potential build that will be actually released to manufacturers. It is sort of like a public beta which gets tested thoroughly before finalising.

Once happy with the RC the developers decide to release it, and the first release is the RTM (Release To Manufacturers), which is sent to the manufacturers so they can start implementing it into their software/devices.

Therefore current RC **MAY** be the RTM but not necessarily. If they find any bugs or issues they will release a new RC test it and than release it to the manufacturers.

Have a look at the following page: [Wikipedia Software Life Cycle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_release_life_cycle)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean F# 2.0 ? Then it is already fully released. 1 day ago, according to Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F_Sharp_(programming_language)